# At breakpoints, Chrome sources shows minified jQuery rather than original jQuery code

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, breakpoints

I'm learning how to use breakpoints with Chrome Dev Tools sources and code written almost entirely in jQuery. When I add a breakpoint to click events a click should (I think) highlight the line of jQuery code which listens for the click on the clicked element. Instead, the display in the sources Code Panel switches from displaying *main.js* (which contains all my jQuery code) to displaying *jquery.min.js*. I think this is minified jQuery. This is of no use to me. I want, if possible, to see the breakpoint highlight the event listener in the original jQuery code. I'm running Chrome in incognito mode.

Comment: jQuery calls your event handlers from its internal event listener functions.

Comment: Do you want to see YOUR code, or just non-minified jQuery code?

Comment: if you want the original jquery code, you'll either have to load the dev version of jquery, not the minified version, or include a source map file.

Comment: @Barmar I want to see MY code but since my code is written in jQuery isn't that the same as seeing *non-minified jQuery code*?

Comment: I meant the readable source code of the jQuery library itself, rather than the minified code of jQuery. Your code isn't minified.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to get an event breakpoint to show your code. The reference to it is in internal jQuery variables.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your code, rather than using event breakpoints.

Comment: @Mike Pomax Kamermans How do I load the *dev version of jquery* and how do I *include a source map file*? I've got the *Enable JavaScript source maps* option box ticked in Dev Tool settings.

Comment: @Barmar. Thanks for the answers so far. If my code isn't minified then what is the code in the file *jquery.min.js*? Also, how do I set a breakpoint in the code? I presume you mean in the jQuery code showing in the sources panel of Dev Tools, rather than in the original code in Notepad++

Comment: jquery.min.js is the code of the jQuery library that your code uses.

Comment: From your post it sounds like you're asking about how to do something with your own code, in your own project, which means you were presumably the one to set up that project and so are in full control of which libraries get loaded. So: wherever you're loading jquery.min.js, change things there. If you're loading from CDN, look up which url you need, if you're loading it as local dependency, get the full version installed, etc. Right now, the only person who knows where to update the file(s) is you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use jQuery to set an event handler, it creates a JavaScript event listener that calls an internal wrapper function of its own, which then calls your callback function, because jQuery event handlers are called a little differently from the way `addEventListener()` works. So if you set an event breakpoint in DevTools, it points to this internal wrapper, not your code, and there's no easy way to get from there to your code. Breakpoints inside the jQuery code are not really very useful unless you're trying to debug jQuery itself.

Instead, just set a normal code breakpoint in your code. For instance, if you have code like

```
$(".classname").click(function() {
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

click on the `console.log` line in the Sources tab to set a breakpoint there.

Comment: Thank you Barmar. This simple problem was beginning to slightly dismantle me but you answer has solved my problem and advanced my knowledge. Also, what I found in trying your answer, is that the *console.log("clicked")* line isn't strictly necessary. A click on a line number (in the number column) where I would write that *console.log* instruction (in a click listener for example), adds a breakpoint at that line number. Then when I click, the code shown in the sources panel jumps to that position (now highlighted) in the original jQuery code. Exactly what I was looking for. Big thanks!!

Comment: That was just an example, of course your handler will have its own code.